# Is the relativistic Dirac equation the most accurate way to calculate energy levels?

Tags: atomic-physics, dirac-equation

I am curious about the current state of the art of calculating energy levels for atoms?  Is there a better way to do this now?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the relativistic Dirac equation the most accurate way to calculate energy levels?

No. Quantum electrodynamics is famously more accurate.

Using the full Standard Model of particle physics would be even more accurate, but probably not noticeably enough to warrant the tremendous amount of additional labor.

Comment: Can you provide the formula?

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke $Z=\int e^{-S}$.

Comment: What do Z, e, and s represent here?

Comment: You asked for a formula, suggesting something simple. But it's not simple -- it's not just a formula. It's a whole theory. AFT's comment is an icon that alludes to the path-integral formulation of quantum field theory, like something you might find in a T-shirt shop, or on a mug. (According to legend, @AccidentalFourierTransform used to collect mugs.)

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke Anyway, here's a less T-shirty way to address your first comment. QED is a quantum field theory, so its observables are expressed in terms of field operators. It has two (kinds of) field operators: those for matter (like electrons and nuclei), and those for the electromagnetic field. These are governed by two equations of motion: one that looks like the Dirac equation, and one that looks like Maxwell's equations -- but the fields are *operators* on a Hilbert space. They're not wavefunctions or classical fields.

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke Applying QED to the calculation of atomic energy levels is not easy. It's *so* difficult that it requires making some pretty messy approximations. But even with those approximations, it's still more accurate than the conventional Dirac equation, where the electromagnetic field is a classical field. The **Lamb shift** is a famous example, so if you search for literature about that, you'll get a taste of what's involved.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which atom. QED corrections are necessary for the Hydrogen atom, or other two-body systems (deuterium, $^3$He$^+$, muonium or positronium), QED corrections are necessary to get energy levels accurate enough to account for the hyperfine splittings, Lamb shift, and the finite lifetime of the excited states. You may have a convenient overview of the current state of things in this review paper by [S.G. Karshenboim](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0509010). Notice that QED effects have to be introduced within carefully controlled approximations at the variance with Schrödinger's or Dirac's equation, exactly solvable for the Coulombic case, QED effects have to be introduced within carefully controlled approximations.

However, the world of atomic spectra (and the need for accurate calculations of energy levels) does not stop at the hydrogen-like problems. The remaining part of the periodic table is made of many-electron atoms. Polyelectronic atoms are a more complex challenge for theoretical calculations due to the electron-electron interaction requiring approximate, numerical methods even at the level of the non-relativistic treatment. Here, many methods are currently used, all based on numerical calculations, including QED effects in an approximate way. Just as an example, one can look at [this quite recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.04923).

Comment: Fair enough.  The bigger the atom the harder the problem.  They can't even accurately calculate the motion of planets in solar system if there are more than one planet in orbit so why would it be easy for atoms?  Let's keep it simple then and stick to hydrogen-1 ground state.

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke I would not be so pessimistic. In some way, we are able to calculate orbits and trajectories accurately enough to send spacecraft here and there in the Solar System and beyond. And also for multi-electron atoms, the calculated spectra are good enough to compare quantitatively with experimental data.